# An application based word problem on linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, applications

A thief escaped from police custody. Since he was sprinter he could clock 40 m/hr. The police realized it after 3 hr and started chasing him in the same direction at 50 m/hr. The police had a dog which could run at 60 m/hr. The dog could run to the thief and then return to the police and then would turn back towards the thief. If it kept on doing so till the police caught the thief. Find the total distance travelled by the dog in the direction of the thief.

Here's what I did - I found out the total time taken by the police to catch the thief which came out to be 12 hours and the distance covered by dog came out as 720 m. I am not able to proceed past this.

Someone Please help

Comment: Is this a trick question? A (human) sprinter cannot keep this sort of pace over a prolonged period of time (approximately 1 mile in 2.4 minutes...wow!)

Comment: Actually, I also have a lot of doubts about a dog being able to cover 720 km in 12 hours.

Comment: No its not a trick question let me edit it. I edited it so it atleast looks true lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, the catch occurs after $12$ hours when the dog has gone a total distance of $720$m; but this is only $600$m from the starting point.

Let the total distance the dog ran back toward the police be $x$. Then the dog must have run $600+x$ distance units toward the thief. So $(600+x)+x=720$.

I'll let you finish it up.

Comment: Hey the catch occurs after 600m but how can we be sure that the dog travels to the thief only once like the question says "The dog could run to the thief and then return to the police and then would turn back towards the thief. If it kept on doing so till the police caught the thief" so what if hypothetically the dog kept on doing this for like 5 times (i know thats not possible but hypothetically) will there be any difference due to this ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times the dog goes back and forth. (In fact, mathematically, theoretically the dog makes infinitely many direction changes...hard on the joints, poor thing). Whatever total distance run back toward the police must be compensated for in extra distance (beyond 600) running toward the thief.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help :)